# JavaScript function onclick runs automatically

Tags: javascript, load

i have this code in while loop in JavaScript. As you can see i am adding every loop to  with ID page, another divs. Every div has onclick handler which can execute MyFunction with variable. My problem is that, my script onlick runs automatically when my page is loaded. But i need to run MyFunction only if i click on the div.

Code:

```
document.getElementById("page").innerHTML += "<div style='width:100px; float:left;' onclick='" + MyFunction(variable) + "'>" + AnotherVariable + "</div>";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a bit off ... try ...

```
document.getElementById("page").innerHTML += "<div style='width:100px; float:left;' onclick='MyFunction(" + variable + ")'>" + AnotherVariable + "</div>";
```

.. if you don't want the function to run.

In particular, look here:

```
"<div ... onclick='MyFunction(" + variable + ")'>"
```

**UPDATE 1**:

"Variable is string."  Then, here's the modification:

```
document.getElementById("page").innerHTML += "<div style='width:100px; float:left;' onclick='MyFunction(\"" + variable + "\")'>" + AnotherVariable + "</div>";
```

Comment: Specifically, using MyFunction(variable) outside of quotes will run it as soon as the script block is rendered inserting the return value into the concatenated string, this is not we want in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but i have new error --> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;... it is saying that is on system.html:1 and first line is <!DOCTYPE html> and there is no ";"

Comment: Is `variable` numeric or a string ... might have to embed quotes if it is a string. use `\"` ...

Comment: Fixed ... should have thought of that.  Sorry.